# Return the file path of the file, not the current directory

Tags: python, sikuli

I have a Python/Sikuli script where I need to store the location of the file in a variable.

I have the IDE on one location, and the file is stored in a different directory. 
IDE: C:\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd 
File: C:\Script\Files\HelloWorld2.sikuli\HelloWorld.py

Now I use `os.getcwd()` to fetch the location of the IDE. 
But how do I return the full directory path of the file "HelloWorld.py"?

I also used `os.path.abspath("HelloWorld2.py")` and `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('HelloWorld2.py'))`. 
But also that didn't work. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: duplicate (or at least related): [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162366/get-location-of-the-py-source-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162366/get-location-of-the-py-source-file)

Comment: Did you try `os.path.realpath(__file__)` ? There are many SO posts about that; the `__file__` attribute is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sikuli seems to have some issue's with the `__file__` 
What does work with Sikuli and Python is:

```
os.path.dirname(getBundlePath())
```

Edit for the question below: 
To get the names of the files that are in the directory you can do:

```
path = os.path.dirname(getBundlePath()) 
directory = os.listdir(path) 
for file in directory: 
    print(file)
```

Comment: But this unfortunately gets the parent directory of the `myscript.sikuli` directory. How do you get the full path to files you put *inside* the `.sikuli` script directory?

Comment: @jhabbott, I added a example code to the answer that would do the trick.To get the complete path for every file, you can make a string and add `path` and `file` to the string.

Comment: That lists the files in the same directory as the script-directory, most likely other unrelated scripts. eg. if I keep my scripts in `/home/joe/sikuliscripts/` and one bundle is `script1.sikuli` - then `getBundlePath()` within that script gives `/home/joe/sikuliscripts/` whereas what I want is `/home/joe/sikuliscripts/script1.sikuli` - I think this is a flaw in Sikuli.

Answer (score 3):

In regular Python, using `__file__` returns the full path of the directory that contains the executed file:

```py
os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
```

However, in Sikuli, the `__file__` reference is undefined:

```py
from sikuli import *
import os

print( os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) ) )
```

When run in Sikuli v2.0.4, we see that `__file__` is [unsupported](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/240852):

```
[error] script [ test2 ] stopped with error in line 6
[error] NameError ( name '__file__' is not defined )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
6: main (  <module> )     print( os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath(__file__) ) )
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

Instead, use `getBundle()`, such as:

```py
from sikuli import *
import os

print( os.path.dirname( getBundlePath() ) )
```

Comment: @tenzin Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771894/python-nameerror-global-name-file-is-not-defined but dirname will return the path of the directory (not the path of the executed file) though