# How to get the path where the library is installed

Tags: path, fortran, shared-libraries

I am working in Linux and I have a library written in Fortran 90 (written by 3rd party), that is reading from a file in the current working directory. I would like to be able to call the resulting library from other folders, hence I need to read the path where the library is installed. How can I know the path to the compiled library within the Fortran code?

I need to store in a variable the path within the code.

For who knows python, I want to achieve the same as

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

but in f90 (see [Get location of the .py source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162366/get-location-of-the-py-source-file))

Using the suggestions in the comment I have done the following:

```
export DATAPATH=`pwd`
make
```

in the Makefile

```
ifort -O3 -fpic -fpp -DDATAPATH -c mysource.f90
```

in `mysource.f90`

```
subroutine mysub
  character(len=100)::dpath
#ifdef DATAPATH
  dpath=DATAPATH
#endif
  open(10,file=trim(dpath)//'initialise.dat')
  ....
  ....
```

the problem is that at compile time I get

```
mysource.f90(42): error #6054: A CHARACTER data type is required in this context.   [1]
    dpath=1
----------^
compilation aborted for mysource.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand at all. Are you asking where is the source code for your library on your hard drive?

Comment: yes, I added a line to the question, in the hope to be more clear

Comment: the initialisation-file is in the same path of the source code (that is the same path as the compiled library). the library needs to know the path to the source code so it can find the initialisation-file

Comment: the message is the following: the data are to be considered part of the source code, and they are not meant to be changed by the user. The user has to be able to run the library anywhere, without caring about where the data-file are stored. I know it is possible to do this on windows, because fortran can know where the library is at run time. I need to do this in linux. thank you

Comment: In that case you can store the configuration with the path in a standard location like `/etc/yourpackage` `/usr/local/etc`, in your home directory or in an environment variable. Consider how modules work and how they set-up the environment variables. For example the variable `NETCDF_PATH` in the NetCDF library and similar. They certainly do not have a hard-coded path in their code. Windows uses registers.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  I have a file.txt to read in the same folder as the source code. the folder of the source code can be moved to another location and recompiled, so i cannot hard code the path to the source code.

Comment: @VladimirF ok so I could pass an environment variable at compile time. I was thinking about using something similar to `dladdr` but your method looks easier

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I am sorry I cannot properly explain my problem. My problem is the same as in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/299601 but in Linux

Comment: Not compile time, run time! You want to be flexible.

Comment: Think about what Intel does when you run `source /opt/intel/your_version_path/ifortvars.sh intel64`

Comment: I certainly have not suggested what you did in EDIT2. I repeat, you **do not** want to fix the path at compile time!

Comment: @VladimirF I don't get your point, why don't I want to fix it at compile time? I would think it is good enough. I am not going to move the .so library after compilation. I require a .so library because that is used in the interface to a python code through CTYPES

Comment: Is the library just for yourself for one computer? Then perhaps. But then you can just hardcode the path into the code by hand...

Comment: if you can provide a working example on how to pass a variable at runtime, it would be helpful.

Comment: when you say "library" do you mean "executable"?

Comment: @agentp lib<name>.so a shared library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish you can fix the path at compile time. Something like

```
gfortran -cpp mylib.f90 -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local/\"

open(newunit=u,file=PREFIX//'mylib/initialise.dat')
```

You must than make sure the library is indeed installed in that place `PREFIX/mylib/`

---

You can create an environment variable containing the path of your data. This variable can be set by hand, in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or in the system `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, there are manyways and they depend if the library is just for one user or for all users of some large computer.

For example
`export MYLIB_PATH='/usr/local/mylib'`

Then you can read the variable in Fortran as

```
CALL get_environment_variable("MYLIB_PATH", mylib_path, status=stat)
```

and the path is now in variable `mylib_path`. You can check the success by checking if `stat==0`.

---

This is not the only possible approach. You can also have a configuration file for your library in your home directory:

```
mkdir $HOME/.config/mylib/
echo "/usr/local/mylib" > $HOME/.config/mylib/path
```

and then you can try to read the path from this file if the environment variable was not set

```
if (stat/=0) then
  CALL get_environment_variable("HOME", home_dir)
  open(newunit=path_unit, file=home_dir//'/.config/mylib/path',status='old',action='read',iostat=stat)
  if (stat/=0) complain

  read(path_unit,'(a)',iostat=stat)  mylib_path
  if (stat/=0) complain
end if
```

Comment: just a word on the `__FILE__` macro: it does not return the name of the file with the full path, but only the name of the file (in this case 'source.f90')

Comment: That is strange, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path

Comment: this is fortran, could it make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make.

Comment: I think you can verify yourself

Comment: I did, it is described in the linked answer. It is compiler specific. "At least for gcc, the value of `__FILE__` is the file path as specified on the compiler's command line." So it depends where do you call your command from and it is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

So when you compiled with -DDATAPATH you have not passed the variable DATAPATH into your code only declared a symbol called DATAPATH as being true, so ifort will substitute DATAPATH as 1. What you need to do is pass it as a value:

```
-DDATAPATH="$(DATAPATH)"
```

For the compilation to work.

Comment: This will not work yet. (hint: parentheses and quotes)

Comment: True missed the quotes, but you need the parentheses as it is a makefile variable not a shell variable?

Comment: There is an export command and then make in the original question, it is a shell variable.

Comment: But its a shell variable that is inserted into the compile command inside the makefile. So its a shell variable that is used as a make variable and thus needs parentheses.

Comment: Ok then, I have no idea why would a makefile contain a full command written like that, but why not. But you still have to escape the quotes as I have it in my answer, otherwise it won't work.