# Get location of the .py source file, within script itself - also after os.chdir

Tags: python, directory

[Get location of the .py source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162366/get-location-of-the-py-source-file) has some ideas but for example accepted one

```
# in /a/b/c/d/e/f/file.py
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.chdir("..")
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

will print

```
/home/reducing_activity/Desktop/tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f
/home/reducing_activity/Desktop/tmp/a/b/c/d/e
```

is there a method that will survive `os.chdir`?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 `Linux 5.4.0-90-lowlatency #101-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 15 20:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (from `uname -a`, computer name snipped)

With `Python 3.8.10` (according to `python3 --version`)

Comment: Possibly a typo in your example - you have the script in `/a/b/c/d/e` but you're saying it will print `/a/b/c/d/e/f`. Additionally, I don't observe the behaviour you described - I get the same path for both print statements.

Comment: @Kemp Thanks fixed! What is you OS and python version?

Comment: Mine is Python 3.8 on Windows 10. I wouldn't expect the value of `__file__` to ever change though, regardless of platform, and it turns out it generally shouldn't... except sometimes it might? Looking around I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616783/3228591

Comment: It's possible that the only completely reliable answer is to save `os.path.abspath(__file__)` somewhere (probably somewhere global for convenience unless you only need it in one scope) before modifying your working directory at all.

Comment: @Kemp That is my current solution but I am not sure is what I see is a bug, intended behavior or what.

Comment: Judging by https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866630/3228591 and some of the other discussion in the other answers it sounds like it's a deliberate optimisation that leads to some unintuitive outcomes. So not a bug as such, but also not entirely useful in cases like yours.